# How do I convert Date and Time of my live Database to a user's local time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, database, webforms

I need help please. I have been trying to get this right but its difficult because I am learning.
I am trying to convert my Database server Time to any user's local time in my web app. I discovered that when I hosted my ASP.Net web application,
and tested it by logging with a pre-registered account, that the Last Login Date and Time was not the same as my local time. So, I needed to convert to my
local Date and Time. How do I convert a time that was inserted using (DateTime.UtcNow), to a local time?

NB: my server is in Europe. I want a situation where any user will be seeing his or her local date and time, regardless of country

Here is how I tried to convert to local time. But it did not work. So please I ask if anybody knows how to do this, please help?

Firstly, this is how I the insert to the LastLogin Date and Time column in my database table. The DataType is datetime.

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string check = "SELECT LastLogin from Users WHERE Id = @Id";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(check, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Session["user"]);
                Session["LastLogin"] = Convert.ToDateTime(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            }
            string UpdateLog = @"UPDATE Users SET LastLogin=@dateandtime WHERE Id = @Id";
            using (SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand(UpdateLog, con))
            {
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateandtime", DateTime.UtcNow);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Session["user"]);
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Before the update of LastLogin column, the LastLogin date and time is first fetched from the table and stored as Session. After successful login, the
LastLogin date and time is called in the Session on next page for display of the Last login date and time.

```
 private void LastLogin()
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT LastLogin FROM Users WHERE Id= @Id", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Session["user"]);
                con.Open();
                DateTime time1 = Convert.ToDateTime(Session["LastLogin"]);//This is where I put the Date and Time
                TimeZoneInfo serverTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time"); // Get Server TimeZone                            
                DateTime dateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(time1, serverTimeZone, TimeZoneInfo.Local); // Convert to local time            
                Timelbl.Text = dateTime.ToString("dddd, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm tt");
            }
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know how I can do this, please? I need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
private void LastLogin()
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT LastLogin FROM Users WHERE Id = @Id", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Session["user"]);
            con.Open();
            DateTime time1 = Convert.ToDateTime(Session["LastLogin"]); // Retrieve server time (stored as UTC)
            TimeZoneInfo serverTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time"); // Server time zone (you can adjust this to match your server's time zone)
            TimeZoneInfo userTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local; // User's local time zone
            DateTime userLocalTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(time1, serverTimeZone, userTimeZone); // Convert to user's local time zone
            Timelbl.Text = userLocalTime.ToString("dddd, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm tt");
        }
    }
}
```

TimeZoneInfo.Local retrieves the user's local time zone based on the server's time zone settings.

Hope it's help

Comment: It's more like what I have in my example, except that you placed Timezone.Info.Local in a line above where the conversion is made. I will test this to see if it will work. Thank  you

Comment: Hi @Dhiren Patel, when you mean that the TimeZoneInfo.Local retrieves the user's local time zone "based on the server's time zone settings". Do I have to adjust the Timezone settings of my server where I host the application, or will the code adjust automatically to user's local timezone?

Comment: Hi @Donald The code snippet I provided retrieves the user's local time zone based on the server's time zone settings. This means that the code will automatically adjust to the user's local time zone without you needing to explicitly adjust the server's time zone settings.

Comment: Hi @Dhiren Patel, I tried the code snippet you provided and it did not achieve the goal. It did not work